OpenAPI with discriminator failing code generation
I am using OpenAPI 3.0.0 and trying to use a discriminator. I am seeing error in my code generation. Appreciate any help. Thanks
` CustomerReq:
  type: object
  properties:
    inputIdentifier:
      description: Input.
      discriminator:
        propertyName: inputType
        mapping:
          ID: '#/components/schemas/IDRequest'
          Number: '#/components/schemas/NumberRequest'
      oneOf:
       - $ref: '#/components/schemas/IDRequest'
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/NumberRequest'
    wId:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/wId'`

The model generation has errors w.r.t incompatible types - NumberRequest cannot be converted to CustomerReqInputIdentifier

Your indentation on the oneOf is invalid.
CustomerReq:
  type: object
  properties:
    inputIdentifier:
      description: Input.
      discriminator:
        propertyName: inputType
        mapping:
          ID: '#/components/schemas/IDRequest'
          Number: '#/components/schemas/NumberRequest'
      oneOf:
       - $ref: '#/components/schemas/IDRequest'
       - $ref: '#/components/schemas/NumberRequest'  # <--this one
    wId:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/wId'


Thank you Jeremy. Still see the error :  The method setInputIdentifier(CustomerReqInputIdentifier) in the type CustomerReq is not applicable for the arguments (NumberRequest)
